# Where can I find the Ubuntu source packaging?

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't seem to be available on http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28448/where-can-i-find-the-ubuntu-source-packaging?/) by [ashuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1854/ashuang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there are no source packages (as for apt-get source).

There is the source based install for the basic ROS system.

For other packages, look in the wiki at ros.org for the packages that you are interested in. Usually there is a download/checkout link.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-09**:
Newer releases now have source debs on packages.ros.org